# how to combine two numpy array to mimic 'absolute' function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have binned data that can be either positive or negative:
example:

- bin_midpoints = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]) # bin_midpoints are midpoints of each bin
- bin_counts = np.array([30, 20, 10, 100, 1, 4]) # bin_counts are frequencies in each bin

I'm trying to mimic 'absolute' so that

- we treat negative values the same way as positive
- we wont have negative midpoints
- bin_counts will be added respectively

expected outcome:

- bin_midpoints = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
- bin_counts = np.array([100, 11, 24, 30])

My attempt:

```
zero_index = np.where(bin_midpoints == 0)[0][0]
left_mid = np.flip(bin_midpoints[0:zero_index])
left_freq = np.flip(bin_counts[0:zero_index])        
right_mid = bin_midpoints[zero_index ::]
right_freq = bin_counts[zero_index ::]
for i in range(0,len(left_freq)):
    try:
        if round(abs(left_freq[i]),2) == round(abs(right_freq[i+1]),2):
            right_freq[i+1] = right_freq[i+1] + left_freq[i] # this doesnt work in the loop, but works outside of it?
        else:
            # less elements on the left
            pass
    except:
        # more elements on the left
        right_freq = np.append(right_freq, left_freq[i])
        right_mid = np.append(right_mid, abs(left_mid[i]))
        
bin_counts = right_freq
bin_midpoints = right_mid
```

Could anybody help me to fix this error, and possibly show better - more optimised method?

Comment: Are the values in `bin_midpoints` always integers?  What is a typical range of values for the midpoints?

Comment: very good question, no, they could be decimals, but the zero is always there

Comment: typical midpoints values are between -700 to 500, but sometimes could be between -0.7 to 0.5,

Answer (score 0):

```
# Method 1 (works only for integer midpoints)

new_counts = np.zeros(abs(bin_midpoints).max() + 1)
new_midpoints = np.zeros(abs(bin_midpoints).max() + 1)
for i, j in zip(bin_midpoints, bin_counts):
    new_counts[abs(i)] += j
    new_midpoints[abs(i)] = abs(i)


# Method 2 Works for non-inters too
zipped = {}
for i, j in zip(bin_midpoints, bin_counts):
    try:
        zipped[abs(round(i,2))] += j
    except:
        zipped[abs(round(i,2))] = j
new_counts = np.flip(np.array(list(zipped.values())))
new_midpoints = np.flip(np.array(list(zipped.keys())))
```